# Serialization of internal class to xml

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, sgen

I ran into problems when trying to xml serialize a class to xml after I changed it from `public` to `internal`. Before I changed protection level it was working fine, so I am looking for a way to get around the public only restriction.

The reason I want it to be internal is that I moved the class into a library and it's not useful outside the library.

A simple example of class layout:

```
[Serializable]
internal class InternalSerializable
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Foo = 5;

    public InternalSerializable()
    {
    }
}
```

Normally `XmlSerializer` is automatically generated and have a random assembly name, so I tried using `sgen.exe` to pre-generate the XmlSerializer and reference it using:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("FileFormats.XmlSerializers")]
```

but when running sgen with `/verbose` switch it says that only public types can be processed.

So I was wondering if anyone know how to trick sgen into processing internal types or otherwise serialize internal classes?

Edit: I got quite a few classes with this problem so I would prefer not to rewrite the whole thing

Comment: possible duplicate of [how-can-i-serialize-internal-classes-using-xmlserializer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156692/how-can-i-serialize-internal-classes-using-xmlserializer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hackish but you could make your class public and mark it with [EditorBrowsable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx) attribute to hide it from intellisense.

```
[EditorBrowsable(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
[Serializable]
public class InternalSerializable
```

In C#, EditorBrowsable work only on compiled assemblies : [Hiding GetHashCode/Equals/ToString from fluent interface classes intellisense in Visual Studio for C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464737/hiding-gethashcode-equals-tostring-from-fluent-interface-classes-intellisense-in)

Comment: Thanks. The library is only for internal use so if I can't find a 'proper' way, I'll probably use this since its easy and accomplish what I was after with using internal.